# whay bootstrap selectpicker not working in laravel collective?

Tags: laravelcollective, bootstrap-selectpicker

```
{!! Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null, 
['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...','clase'=>'selectpicker form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the word `class`.  Try:

```
{!! Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null, 
['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...','class'=>'selectpicker form-control']) !!}
```